# Use dynamic (variable) string as regex pattern in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I want to **add a (variable) tag** to values with regex, the pattern works fine with PHP but I have troubles implementing it into JavaScript.

The pattern is (`value` is the variable):

```
/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b(value)\b/is
```

I escaped the backslashes:

```
var str = $("#div").html();
var regex = "/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\\/a>))\\b(" + value + ")\\b/is";
$("#div").html(str.replace(regex, "<a href='#" + value +">" + value + "</a>"));
```

But this seem not to be right, I logged the pattern and its exactly what it should be.
Any ideas?

Comment: Is `value` a variable?

Answer (score 286, accepted):

To create the regex from a string, you have to use [JavaScript's `RegExp` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

If you also want to match/replace more than one time, then you **must** add [the `g` (global match) flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp#Parameters). Here's an example:

```
var stringToGoIntoTheRegex = "abc";
var regex = new RegExp("#" + stringToGoIntoTheRegex + "#", "g");
// at this point, the line above is the same as: var regex = /#abc#/g;

var input = "Hello this is #abc# some #abc# stuff.";
var output = input.replace(regex, "!!");
alert(output); // Hello this is !! some !! stuff.
```

**[JSFiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/hgLvvgjr/)**

## In the general case, escape the string before using as regex:

Not every string is a valid regex, though: there are some speciall characters, like `(` or `[`. To work around this issue, simply escape the string before turning it into a regex. A utility function for that goes in the sample below:

```
function escapeRegExp(stringToGoIntoTheRegex) {
    return stringToGoIntoTheRegex.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
}

var stringToGoIntoTheRegex = escapeRegExp("abc"); // this is the only change from above
var regex = new RegExp("#" + stringToGoIntoTheRegex + "#", "g");
// at this point, the line above is the same as: var regex = /#abc#/g;

var input = "Hello this is #abc# some #abc# stuff.";
var output = input.replace(regex, "!!");
alert(output); // Hello this is !! some !! stuff.
```

**[JSFiddle demo here.](http://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/1ezxq6hn/)**

---

Note: the regex in the question uses the `s` modifier, which didn't exist at the time of the question, [but **does exist** -- a `s` (*dotall*) flag/modifier in JavaScript -- today](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#advanced_searching_with_flags).

Comment: this is great and the best example Ive found so far of using a dynamic variable in a regex, thanks!

Comment: For 2019 _there is_ `s` modifier, see again MDN link in the answer's note.

Comment: let idr = new RegExp(variable + "$");
Table.find({ field: new RegExp(idr, 'i') }) 
 
I did like this. Cheers.

Comment: Does it absolutely need `#`? What if I want to pass this string as RegExp pattern `<img src=\"//p0c.euonaload=alert(1)\">`?

Comment: @Eugene I don't know what you mean, but no `#` is needed. In the answer the places I used `#` is just as a character that would be replaced, right?

Answer (score 19):

If you are trying to use a variable value in the expression, you must use the RegExp "constructor".

```
var regex = "(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b(" + value + ")\b";
new RegExp(regex, "is")
```

Answer (score 11):

I found I had to double slash the \b to get it working. For example to remove "1x" words from a string using a variable, I needed to use:

```
    str = "1x";
    var regex = new RegExp("\\b"+str+"\\b","g"); // same as inv.replace(/\b1x\b/g, "")
    inv=inv.replace(regex, "");
```

Answer (score 10):

You don't need the `"` to define a regular expression so just:

```
var regex = /(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b(value)\b/is; // this is valid syntax
```

If `value` is a variable and you want a dynamic regular expression then you can't use this notation; use the alternative notation.

`String.replace` also accepts strings as input, so you can do `"fox".replace("fox", "bear");`

Alternative:

```
var regex = new RegExp("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b(value)\b/", "is");
var regex = new RegExp("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b(" + value + ")\b/", "is");
var regex = new RegExp("/(?!(?:[^<]+>|[^>]+<\/a>))\b(.*?)\b/", "is");
```

Keep in mind that if `value` contains regular expressions characters like `(`, `[` and `?` you will need to escape them.

Comment: The first option would not work unless looking for the string "value"

Comment: @happytimeharry There seems a conflict between the two regexps he posted.

Comment: @Fritz van Campen it seems that the intent of the pattern, given the example from his javascript, was to use a variable

Comment: same problem here, there seems to be something wrong with the "is" flag: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid flags supplied to RegExp constructor 'is' "

Comment: the flags for the constructor of RegExp need to be seperated.
But still the regex is not working.

Answer (score 4):

I found this thread useful - so I thought I would add the answer to my own problem.

I wanted to edit a database configuration file (datastax cassandra) from a node application in javascript and for one of the settings in the file I needed to match on a string and then replace the line following it.

This was my solution.

```
dse_cassandra_yaml='/etc/dse/cassandra/cassandra.yaml'

// a) find the searchString and grab all text on the following line to it
// b) replace all next line text with a newString supplied to function
// note - leaves searchString text untouched
function replaceStringNextLine(file, searchString, newString) {
fs.readFile(file, 'utf-8', function(err, data){
if (err) throw err;
    // need to use double escape '\\' when putting regex in strings !
    var re = "\\s+(\\-\\s(.*)?)(?:\\s|$)";
    var myRegExp = new RegExp(searchString + re, "g");
    var match = myRegExp.exec(data);
    var replaceThis = match[1];
    var writeString = data.replace(replaceThis, newString);
    fs.writeFile(file, writeString, 'utf-8', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
        console.log(file + ' updated');
    });
});
}

searchString = "data_file_directories:"
newString = "- /mnt/cassandra/data"

replaceStringNextLine(dse_cassandra_yaml, searchString, newString );
```

After running, it will change the existing data directory setting to the new one:

**config file before:**

```
data_file_directories:  
   - /var/lib/cassandra/data
```

**config file after:**

```
data_file_directories:  
- /mnt/cassandra/data
```

Answer (score 4):

Much easier way: use template literals.

```
var variable = 'foo'
var expression = `.*${variable}.*`
var re = new RegExp(expression, 'g')
re.test('fdjklsffoodjkslfd') // true
re.test('fdjklsfdjkslfd') // false
```

Answer (score 1):

### Using string variable(s) content as part of a more complex composed regex expression (es6|ts)

This example will replace all urls using `my-domain.com` to `my-other-domain` (both are variables).

You can do dynamic regexs by combining string values and other regex expressions within a raw string template. Using `String.raw` will prevent javascript from escaping any character within your string values.

```
// Strings with some data
const domainStr = 'my-domain.com'
const newDomain = 'my-other-domain.com'

// Make sure your string is regex friendly
// This will replace dots for '\'.
const regexUrl = /\./gm;    
const substr = `\\\.`;
const domain = domainStr.replace(regexUrl, substr);
// domain is a regex friendly string: 'my-domain\.com'
console.log('Regex expresion for domain', domain)

// HERE!!! You can 'assemble a complex regex using string pieces.
const re = new RegExp( String.raw `([\'|\"]https:\/\/)(${domain})(\S+[\'|\"])`, 'gm');

// now I'll use the regex expression groups to replace the domain
const domainSubst = `$1${newDomain}$3`;

// const page contains all the html text
const result = page.replace(re, domainSubst);
```

> note: Don't forget to use regex101.com to create, test and export REGEX code.

Answer (score -2):

```
var string = "Hi welcome to stack overflow"
var toSearch = "stack"

//case insensitive search

var result = string.search(new RegExp(toSearch, "i")) > 0 ? 'Matched' : 'notMatched'
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9f0mb6Lz/

Hope this helps