# "TypeError: obj.indexOf is not a function" error when writing a selenium test script

Tags: javascript, selenium, cucumber

I'm currently making an automated test script using Selenium Webdriver and Cucumber for my company's website. To do this I have used [Matt-B's example](https://github.com/Matt-B/cucumber-js-selenium-webdriver-example) as a start. Since getting the files, I modified the contents of google.feature to:

```
  Feature: Changing Pages
    As an internet user
    In order to move through a website
    I want to be able to click a button and go to another page

    Scenario: Digital3rd Testing page
      Given I am on the Digital3rd website
      When I click the "Testing" button
      Then I should go to "../testing"
```

And have now started modifying google-steps.js to this:

```
'use strict';

var expect = require('chai').expect;

module.exports = function() {
  this.World = require('../support/world.js').World;

  this.Given(/^I am on the Digital(\d+)rd website$/, function (arg1, callback) { //declaring function that relates to Cucumber Script
        this.driver.get('http://www.Digital3rd.org'); //open intended website
    callback(null, 'set-up');
  });

  this.When(/^I click the "([^"]*)" button$/, function (arg1, callback) { //declaring function that relates to Cucumber Script  
      this.onload = //when the page loads...
         this.driver.manage().window().maximize(); //maximise the screen...
         this.driver.findElement({id: 'menu-item-24'}).click(); //click the "Testing" button.
    callback(null, 'test');
  });

  this.Then(/^I should go to "([^"]*)"$/, function (promise) {
        var wbaddrss = this.driver.getCurrentUrl();
        return expect(wbaddrss).to.contain('/testing');
  });
};
```

The first two steps work fine by opening the website, maximising it and clicking the button. I'm now trying to validate that I am on the correct page using a section of the URL. Any help with fixing the "TypeError: obj.indexOf is not a function" error or with giving me an alternative would be appreciated thanks. Sorry if it's a simple answer but this is the first time I've done anything like this.

The full error code I get in the console is:

```
 TypeError: obj.indexOf is not a function
     at Assertion.include (C:\Users\User\Test program\node_modules\chai\lib\chai\core\assertions.js:228:45)
     at Assertion.assert (C:\Users\User\Test program\node_modules\chai\lib\chai\utils\addChainableMethod.js:84:49)
     at World.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Test program\features\step_definitions\google-steps.js:32:30)
     at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:420:9)
     at process._tickCallback (node.js:349:13)
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same issue with `expect(object).to.contain('string')` in Chai and would like to step through it to find out what's going wrong.  Meanwhile, you can judiciously use JS regular expressions with the `match()` function rather than `contain()`:

```
expect(object1).to.match(/String to contain/);
expect(object2).to.match(/^Exact string to match$/);

expect(object3).to.match(/^This string might contain other things/);
expect(object3).to.match(/before it ends here$/);
```

To use variables in the regex, see this other SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886301/949911/

Answer (score -1):

**indexOf is Array Property and not of object**

Comment: Ok, well I found multiple sites saying you can use it to find a substring from a string which was what I was trying here

Comment: what is your obj? is it a string?

Comment: I assume that as if you look at my code, I get the URL, save it to a var and then run it through Chai's "expect"

Comment: I'm unsure, I think it appears in the code from the Chai framework - I've amended the original question with the full error message

Comment: i m not familiar with  Chai framework... but i guess you have issue with this line   var wbaddrss = this.driver.getCurrentUrl(); return expect(wbaddrss).to.contain('/testing');

Comment: Sorry, it's not a framework, it's an assertion library, the page is here: http://chaijs.com/

Comment: its completely new to me.i will suggest you go through documentation of that library  and confirm first that obj is string.

Comment: This should be a comment.