# Regex match string with whitespace if search query has no whitespace

Tags: javascript, regex, search

edit to clarify: `oneword` is a searchquery a user might use. I need to match both `oneword`, `one word` or `word one` with this regex

---

how to match a string with or without whitespace in any given order?

This is my current query `/^(?=.*one)(?=.*word).*$/i`
credits: http://www.rubular.com/r/QFEfj9lMn3

So given the text 
`oneword one word word one` and the searchquery `/^(?=.*one)(?=.*word).*$/i` matches all three, but `/^(?=.*oneword).*$/i` only matches the first part of the text.

Are there better ways to fix this than by adding one optional character in front of every single letter?

thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you please clearly state what result you would like from the regex match.

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, couldn't you just write the two possibilities explicitly, like: `/one\s*word|word\s*one/`?

Comment: I get the string from a searchQuery. A user might search for `one word` or `oneword`. I would like to create a regex query that matches for both search strings all three variations of `oneword one word word one `
So the problem is not the word order but matching it if the searchquery is either written with a whitespace or without (the other way around is rather trivial)

Comment: @TomLord thanks for you help, but how would I know where to place the optional character in oneword? Other examplse might be match `stackoverflow` to both `stack overflow` and `stackoverflow`

Comment: You'll need to have **some** way of knowing what the two words are. It would not be practical to perform a search like: `s ?t ?a ?c ?k ?o ?v ?e ?r ?f ?l ?o ?w`

Comment: Unless you have some practical way to predict how to split the word, I'd suggest using ElasticSearch instead of regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this simple regex generation

```js
function showMatches(sampleInput, searchInput) {
  console.log(sampleInput, searchInput);
  if (sampleInput.length && searchInput.length) {
    var regexStr = searchInput.split(" ").join("\\\s*") + "|" + searchInput.split(" ").reverse().join("\\\s*");
    var regex = new RegExp(regexStr, "gi");
    //console.log(regex);
    console.log(sampleInput.match(regex))
  }
}
showMatches("one word word one oneword", "one word");
```

**Explanation**

- **Split** the input by space to get words.
- **Join** them by `\\\s*`
- **Repeat** the same for reversed words
- **Combine** both `"|"`

**Note** - You may also want to escape special regular expression characters from search inputs using an approach shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17886301/1984039).

Comment: Thank you for your well explained answer, but I have no idea where to split these two words. `searchInput` might be `oneword` which does not match `one word`

Comment: You can't, unless you have a dictionary of all words and you want to first get a match of possible words. Match `oneword` from input to `word one` in sample involves *natural language processing* which is far too broad.