# How to Use RegExp to count substr composed of identical character in a string using js

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Is there any way in js to use RegExp and `str.match()` to count combinations of substrings in a string? I'm trying to achieve the following:

given a string:

```
'999999000'
```

I need to find all the combination of `99` that exist in the string, the expected result for the above string is 5 as you can combine the indexes in the following pairs to create a `99`:

```
index 0 and 1
index 1 and 2
index 2 and 3
index 3 and 4
index 4 and 5
```

now I've tried using the match method the following way:

```js
    let re = new RegExp("99","gi");
    let matches = "999999000".match(re).length;
    console.log(matches);
```

but the result it throws it's 3.

note that the above snippet would work for the following case:

```js
    let re = new RegExp("99","gi");
    let matches = "00990099099099".match(re).length;
    console.log(matches);
```

I know this problem can be solved by iterating on the string to find all the'99' combinations, but I want to solve it using regex and `str.match`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a positive [lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to assert 2 times a 9:

[`(?=(9{2}))`](https://regex101.com/r/LGY0v5/1)

```js
const strings = [
  "999999000",
  "00990099099099"
];
let re = new RegExp("(?=(9{2}))", "gi");
strings.forEach((s) => {
  console.log(s + " ==> " + s.match(re).length);
});
```

Comment: now that solves the problem for that specific case, how can i use a variable in the regExp object for example  instead of '99' i have  the substring stored in a variable X ?

Comment: For this example you could use the RegExp constructor and pass your variable `new RegExp("(?=(" + variable + "{2}))","gi");` . I think  [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885855/use-dynamic-variable-string-as-regex-pattern-in-javascript/17886301) can be helpful about escaping what you pass as a variable.

Comment: thanks, I used your answer to solve my problem, your answer worked for me only when the substring was length 2, but would fail for other cases, I end up doing the following:
`let P= "099990999099990909099";   let test= "(?=("+P+"{1}))"
let re = new RegExp(test,"gi");
let matches = arrayG.match(re).length;`