# regex match begining using variable

Tags: javascript, match

So i want this correct `match()` syntax with variable `var a = 'breaksmooth';` and `var b = 'bre';` , what i knew if i'm not using any variable or at least search in variable : `if(a.match(/^bre/)) return true;` i just want to achieve this `if(a.match(/^b/);` where `b` is `var b` which is give me error .i dont want to change `var b` with `b = /^bre/`. any solution ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use dynamic (variable) string as regex pattern in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885855/use-dynamic-variable-string-as-regex-pattern-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method:

```
var a = 'breaksmooth';
var b = 'bre';
var re = new RegExp(b, 'g');
a.match(re)
```

Comment: g flag is for global match.

Comment: And what do you mean by "global match"?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to check whether `a` starts with `b`, you don't need a regex at all:

```js
var a = 'breaksmooth';
var b = 'bre';
if (a.startsWith(b)) {
    console.log('yes');
}
```

See the [`startsWith`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) method.

On the other hand, if you want to create a regex from a string, you can use the [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) constructor:

```
var b = 'bre';
var regex = new RegExp('^' + b);  // same as /^bre/
```

You don't even need a separate variable:

```
if (a.match(new RegExp('^' + b))) {
```