# adding dynamic values to regex

Tags: javascript

I am having a regex where i check the input is having 6 digit number. I am able to achieve it with the below refgex

```
/^\d{6}$/gm.test("123456")
```

I have used this regex in multiple places so I am trying to make it as a function

```
function testNumber(number, digitLength = 6){
  return /^\d{6}$/gm.test(number)
}
```

Now in some places the digitLength is of 3 and in some places its 4, now how can i interpolate the digitLength in the regex so i can pass as much the digitLength instead of hardcoding 6 in the regex.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: ```new RegExp(`^\\d{${digitLength}}$`, 'gm').test(number)```

Comment: @CherryDT yep template literals would be easy but where to add so that why I am confused, without failing the regex

Comment: so there is no way to interpolate variables inside regex string ?

Comment: @CherryDT let me try and will update

Comment: See also: [Use dynamic (variable) string as regex pattern in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17885855/use-dynamic-variable-string-as-regex-pattern-in-javascript)

Comment: @CherryDT thanks it worked, if you can add an answer it will be helpful for future references for others

Comment: It's essentially a duplicate that's why I didn't provide an answer because duplicates should be linked to the existing answer and closed and not answered separately. You should see a box above your question that asks you if the linked question's answers matched your question - you can just choose "yes" there to close this question.

Answer (score 2):

**You are looking for (your regex):**

```js
function testNumber(number, digitLength = 6){
  return new RegExp(`^\\d{${digitLength}}$`, 'gm').test(number);
}
```

Refs: [RegExp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

**Same, but optimized:**
As [@Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6567275/thomas) noticed, you don't need `g` flag in your case, because you always match global (full string), and you don't need `m` flag too, because you accept one-line inputs. So regex like this is enough:

```js
function testNumber(number, digitLength = 6){
  return new RegExp(`^\\d{${digitLength}}$`).test(number);
}
```

Comment: Why `gm`? There's no need for *global* nor *multiline* here. We always match the entire string.

Comment: @Thomas make sence, I'll update answer, thanks for advice!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of a dynamic regex you could also do it like this:

```
function testNumber(number, digitLength = 6){
  return number.length === digitLength // check expected length
    && /^\d+$/.test(number);           // and that it is all digits
}
```